# Mapping prevent null instead of string value

Tags: asp.net, automapper

I'm trying to map the situation of equipment using this code:

```
CreateMap<Equipement, EquipementDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Libellesituation, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
        src.Lignesituationequipements == null || !src.Lignesituationequipements.Any()
            ? "Situation not assigned yet"
            : src.Lignesituationequipements
                .Where(l => l.Datefinsituation == "N/A" || DateTime.ParseExact(l.Datefinsituation, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > DateTime.Today)
                .OrderBy(l => DateTime.ParseExact(l.Datedebutsituation, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                .Select(l => l.Code1Navigation.Libelle)
                .LastOrDefault() ?? "Situation not assigned yet"
        ));
```

It's working when the situation is equal to null and returns this message

> Situation not assigned yet

but when the equipment has instances on the lignesituation table, it returns NULL instead of the situation name.